# How to install libfaac-dev?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I edited `/etc/apt/source.list` to have `restricted` and `partner` repository, but the results always:

```
sudo apt-get install libfaac-dev ....
....
E: Unable to locate package libfaac-dev
```

The package is used by audio codecs, and `ffmpeg` uses it.

Comment: On my Ubuntu desktop 11.04 Natty it will install without any trouble. Try change the source server maybe?

Comment: what version of ubuntu you are using?

Answer (score 15):

`libfaac-dev` is in multiverse repository. So, you need to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to include multiverse repository as well.
`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main restricted universe multiverse`

After you change it, run the following command to install `libfaac-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libfaac-dev
```

Answer (score 8):

This problem was KILLING me but I figured it out.  It turns out that I needed to add the following lines in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
```

Meaning that, for the multiverse, you should have 4 lines in total:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile it

```
$ wget -O fdk-aac.tar.gz https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac/tarball/master
$ tar xzvf fdk-aac.tar.gz
$ cd mstorsjo-fdk-aac*
$ autoreconf -fiv
$ ./configure --prefix="$HOME" --disable-shared
$ make
$ make install
```